# Out of bound external function calls with nonlinear solvers in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a simple Modelica model calls an external function (C code via ExternalObject) that (nonlinearly) interpolates properties over the space s1, s2, s3 where s are all bound between 0 and 1. The model needs to invert/solve f1 = f1(s1,s2,s3), f2 = f2(s1,s2,s3), f3 = f3(s1,s2,s3) to find the initial s given known f. Unfortunately, the OpenModelica nonlinear solvers attempt to evaluate f using out of bounds s, despite defining s1,s2,s3 as:

```
  Real s1(min = 0.0, max = 1.0, start = 0.5, nominal = 0.01);
  Real s2(min = 0.0, max = 1.0, start = 0.5, nominal = 0.01);
  Real s3(min = 0.0, max = 1.0, start = 0.5, nominal = 0.01);
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way of dealing with this other than to pull the inversion into the external C object. Have I missed something?

Comment: Some tools have a flag/setting to enforce these bounds, but OpenModelica does not seem to have such a flag. https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html

Comment: If I recall correctly, the kinsol solver respects bounds in OpenModelica but other solvers do not.

Comment: Much obliged for those responses. I tried kinsol, but the log reads 'update static data of non-linear system solvers', the program slowly sucks up almost all available memory and then seemingly makes no progress. Further investigation required.

Comment: I have found that if my initial guesses are adequately accurate, then the solver does not evaluate the function out of bounds.